# Button transition is not working on ipad

Tags: css, transition

I have a button that works fine on a desktop with a mouse, but not on ipad.
It is the 
**transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;** 
AND
**transform: scale(0.8);**
that aren't working.

I also don't know why its linking to Twitter in this Fiddle, but not a big deal.

I changed the :hover in MQ to :focus but still not working.

Is there a fix? If not, how to disable in media query?

https://jsfiddle.net/q9zqLk84/3/

```
    .iconCol .sizing{
        transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }

    .iconCol .sizing:hover {
        transform: scale(0.8);
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
        -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
        -o-transform: scale(0.8);

    }
```

Comment: You're missing the `transform` on the prefixed declarations.

Comment: It works with or without it there.
It still doesnt work on ipad either way.

Comment: Try vendor prefixes first.